# Electron <webview> Push Notification Count in Title

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm developing an app for Windows using Electron's webViewTag to load WhatsApp Web.
Currently, all notifications are working, I get desktop toast messages, but I was wondering if it's possible to get a notification count in the title bar of my app from webview.
I tried webview.GetTitle but it only returns the Title of the website I'm Loading:

```
// Inside my renrer.js
const webview = document.querySelector('webview');
webview.addEventListener('did-finish-load', () => document.title = webview.getTitle());
```

This changes my app's title to "WhatsApp Web", but what I want is like "(n) WhatsApp" when there are new messages or notifications.
When loading WhatsApp Web directly from the browser window, it automatically works and I get the message count, but I lose functionality to run my own custom HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to this, I've found a solution.
Not sure if Electron version is relevant, but I'm using v15.0.0

Inside render.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const whatsAppWin = document.querySelector('webview');

whatsAppWin.addEventListener('page-title-updated', function () {
  var whatsAppTitle = whatsAppWin.getTitle();
  ipcRenderer.send('title-update', whatsAppTitle);
})
```

Then in main.js:

```
ipcMain.on('title-update', function (event, whatsAppTitle) {
  mainWindow.setTitle(whatsAppTitle);
})
```

This will keep looking for a title update in webview, and send the string with ipcRenderer to main.js nad set the title of mainWindow

Answer (score 0):

This seems totally possible as long as you are keeping track of the notification count somewhere else in your code. That might look something like this:

```js
const webview = document.querySelector('webview');
const notifications = // <source of notification counter>

  webview.addEventListener('did-finish-load', () => {
    document.title = webview.getTitle()
  })

 webview.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const webviewTitle = webview.getTitle()
    const documentTitle = `(${notifications}) ${webviewTitle}`
    document.title = documentTitle
  })
}
```

Comment: What would the source of notifications be? Would I have to know how whatsapp web sends push notifications?

Comment: I don't have enough experience there to suggest what to hook into to get that information but I would hope it exposes some type of current notification count that you can tap into.